# What is the seminal reference for quantum computing?

Tags: resource-request

If someone wanted to pinpoint the seminal reference on the subject of quantum computing, what would it be?  Thanks.

Comment: In which context? Where is was invented? Where you can learn about it?

Comment: At the minute, this is too broad for there to be a definitive answer without more context - do you mean theory, experiment, a specific type or detail about quantum computing, somewhere you can learn to program one, a list of the big papers (check the [timeline of quantum computing Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_quantum_computing)) or something else? As there's no specific answer to this, I'll close it in the meantime, but feel free to ask in [chat] and hopefully we can either answer your question or get it narrowed down enough for someone else to answer it

Answer (score 2):

*Quantum Computation and Quantum Information* by Nielsen and Chuang.

Comment: Thanks for that @ChainedSymmetry.  I guess my follow-on question would be:  what _journal article_ would be considered the seminal reference?  Additional thoughts appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of any journal articles that would qualify as a seminal reference.  In terms of most significant, I would say Shor's [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/365700) _Algorithms for quantum computation: discrete logarithms and factoring_. This was a major turning point in convincing the world that quantum computing was more than an academic curiosity.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  That would put the start of the topic around 1994 or so.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @ad2004 The start of the topic was almost certainly with [Feynman](https://permalink.lanl.gov/object/tr?what=info:lanl-repo/lareport/LA-UR-02-4969-02).  Shor's algorithm was just the inflection point when it began to become mainstream.  At least that's how I see it.

Comment: @ad2004 You should make your question more specific!